# UIWebView youtube video responding to UIAppearance

Tags: ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiappearance

i'm starting to get really frustrated...

first MFMessageComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController were inheriting the UIAppearance changes I was making to my view controller...

I finally sorted that out by subclassing my navigationController and containing my UIAppearance changes to the custom navigationController's class...

But now I have the problem all over again with a youtube video in my uiwebview. once again i have a subclassed viewController and i'm using appearanceWhenContainedIn:myViewController, but the youtube video appears to be contained within my custom view controller....

this is really starting to bug me. apple explicitly says to not customize these views, in the case of the youtube video, i'm not even using mpmovieplayer its just right out of uiwebview... i really don't want to have to drop the whole mpmovieplayer framework into my project just to set nil values for uiappearance for this class...

and even if i do that, i'm unsure how to get the default titletextattributes to reapply them....

Why are these views responding to uiappearance in the first place? shouldn't apple have explicitly disallowed them from inheriting uiappearance changes?

please if anybody has advice let me know

Comment: What exact you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to stop the embedded youtube video player in my uiwebview from inheriting the UIAppearance changes. the youtube player is showing up with my custom buttons, which i imagine is sure to result in app rejection.

Comment: i have the same problem. have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem and it's incredibly frustrating. My experience with UIAppearance has been 98% awesome and 2% excruciating. I have a similar problem with UIWebView keyboard accessory toolbars getting styled incorrectly.